# How to Create a MongoID in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, mongodb, uniqueidentifier

I need to create a MongoId in XCode because I upload a file to my server with that MongoId as its name. Then, if the file uploaded successfully, I add an entry to my servers that says a photo was uploaded with that MongoId. I just need to generate the hex string in XCode. Is  there any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Could you give a bit more explanation? Where does MongoDB come in to the picture? Normally, you use the driver to generate the ObjectId (the default unique identifier for a document that I think you are referring to when you say MongoId). But also note that there's no requirement that the _id unique identifier be an ObjectId. It could be a string, a number, or even an embedded document; it just has to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the code below to create a UUID, then cut off the last parts of the string to make it the same length as a mongoId. This is a workaround right now but gets the job done.

```
  -(NSString *)uniqueFileName {
   CFUUIDRef theUniqueString = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
   CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUniqueString);
   CFRelease(theUniqueString);
   return (__bridge NSString *)string;
   }
```